# creating a schema with products with infinite categories and infinite sub-categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, schema

I've been doing a lot of research on what is the best approach to developing a schema for a new feature on a project I am working on.

I will have products that can be associated with an infinite number of categories and in infinite number of sub-categories.

As I started get frustrated I started to think that maybe I am just over thinking it. I'm wondering if the active record associations below make sense to you and you can foresee any possible gotchas.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  has_many :sub_categories, through: :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :products
end

class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the fields on a category and the fields on a subcategory?

Comment: no duplicates between the categories or sub-categories ie there may be a "table" category with sub-categories "bed table" "night stand"

Comment: But do they have the same data fields?  In your "table" example the both have a name field.

Comment: oh sorry, I'm not totally certain yet if both tables will have the exact same data fields but it is likely there will be some overlap. In other words it is likely they will both have a "name" field.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, just go with what you have.

IF you start seeing a lot of overlap in both data and behavior (instance methods) or if you find yourself always wanting to access categories and sub categories together you could start looking at:

1. [Self joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) - which would let you keep both categories in the same table and as the same type of model
2. [Ancestory](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) - additional flexibility for a full-on tree structure of data